# Aui button with name attribute's value not submit

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have some form in AUI taglib, each have two submit button with same name and different value. as follow :

```
    <aui:form name="generalInformationForm" action="${generalInformation}" method="post">
    <aui:fieldset label="company.contact.info">
    <aui:layout>
    <aui:column>
<aui:input type="text" name="generalInformationDto.distanceFromResidentailArea"
                    label="distance.from.residential.area" inlineLabel="true" >
                    <aui:validator name="number"></aui:validator>
                </aui:input>
    </aui:column>
    </aui:layout>
    </aui:fieldset>
    <aui:button-row>
    <aui:button type="button" value="back.text" first="true" onClick="<%=showLicenseDetailsInformation.toString()%>" />
            <aui:button type="submit" value="save.as.draft" name="buttonName" />
            <aui:button type="cancel" value="cancel.text" />
            <aui:button type="submit" value="next.text" last="true" name="buttonName" />
        </aui:button-row>
    </aui:form>
```

in some form it's work but some form it's not work

what the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

import following taglib in your jsp

> <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
>   You must be missing some imports.

What do you mean by value is not getting on server? Do you mean to say?

for getting named value in controller you can use something like this

> String number= request.getParameter("number");

Comment: I want Button Value on server